# Extracting Data from a DICOMDIR file using Pydicom

Tags: python, dicom, pydicom

I'm unable to read in a DICOM file as I usually would, citing the error:

```
AttributeError: 'DicomDir' object has no attribute 'DirectoryRecordSequence'
```

I've tried:

- pydicom.fileset.FileSet
- using specific tags with dcmread
- pydicom.filereader.read_dicomdir
- pydicom.filereader.read_partial
- using force=True in dcmread

pydicom.filereader.read_file_meta_info is about the only thing that's not returned an error and yields;

```
(0002, 0000) File Meta Information Group Length  UL: 172
(0002, 0001) File Meta Information Version       OB: b'\x00\x01'
(0002, 0002) Media Storage SOP Class UID         UI: Media Storage Directory Storage
(0002, 0003) Media Storage SOP Instance UID      UI: 2.25.330614241706723499239981063503184149269
(0002, 0010) Transfer Syntax UID                 UI: Explicit VR Little Endian
(0002, 0012) Implementation Class UID            UI: 1.3.6.1.4.1.30071.8
(0002, 0013) Implementation Version Name         SH: 'fo-dicom 4.0.7'
```

Moreover, the image is supposed to be a regular DICOM file, not a DICOMDIR. I can open the file in ImageJ and view header information there so I know the data is recoverable.
Is there a way for me to read in this file in Python or alternatively force it to ignore looking for DirectoryRecordSequence?

Edit:
Code and stacktrace from using FileSet:

```
from pydicom.fileset import FileSet
fs = FileSet("unprocessed.dcm")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-2b6ba2e435fe> in <module>
      1 from pydicom.fileset import FileSet
----> 2 fs = FileSet("unprocessed.dcm")

c:\****\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pydicom\fileset.py in __init__(self, ds)
    998         # Check the DICOMDIR dataset and create the record tree
    999         if ds:
-> 1000             self.load(ds)
   1001         else:
   1002             # New File-set

c:\****\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pydicom\fileset.py in load(self, ds_or_path, include_orphans, raise_orphans)
   1641             ds = ds_or_path
   1642         else:
-> 1643             ds = dcmread(ds_or_path)
   1644 
   1645         sop_class = ds.file_meta.get("MediaStorageSOPClassUID", None)

c:\****\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pydicom\filereader.py in dcmread(fp, defer_size, stop_before_pixels, force, specific_tags)
   1027         stop_when = _at_pixel_data
   1028     try:
-> 1029         dataset = read_partial(
   1030             fp,
   1031             stop_when,

c:\****\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pydicom\filereader.py in read_partial(fileobj, stop_when, defer_size, force, specific_tags)
    879             DeprecationWarning
    880         )
--> 881         ds = DicomDir(
    882             fileobj,
    883             dataset,

c:\****\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dicomdir.py in __init__(self, filename_or_obj, dataset, preamble, file_meta, is_implicit_VR, is_little_endian)
     94 
     95         self.patient_records: List[Dataset] = []
---> 96         self.parse_records()
     97 
     98     def parse_records(self) -> None:

c:\****\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dicomdir.py in parse_records(self)
    125 
    126         # Build the mapping from file offsets to records
--> 127         records = self.DirectoryRecordSequence
    128         if not records:
    129             return

c:\****\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    834             return {}
    835         # Try the base class attribute getter (fix for issue 332)
--> 836         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
    837 
    838     @property

AttributeError: 'DicomDir' object has no attribute 'DirectoryRecordSequence'
```

​

Comment: Judging by the SOP class (Media Storage Directory Storage) it _is_ a DICOMDIR file. Actually using `pydicom.fileset.FileSet` should work. Can you add a stacktrace (together with the code that cause it)?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Hi MrBean here's the code (following stacktrace edited into original question). Just to confirm also, it's Pydicom v2.2.2:

`from pydicom.fileset import FileSet
fs = FileSet("unprocessed.dcm")`

Answer (score 2):

*pydicom* reads the dataset correctly, but because it identifies as *Media Storage Directory* it gets processed by the deprecated [DicomDir](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/reference/generated/pydicom.dicomdir.DicomDir.html#pydicom.dicomdir.DicomDir) class, even when passed directly to the `FileSet` class. Because the dataset isn't a valid *Media Storage Directory* instance this fails, producing the exception seen.

You should be able to fix this by changing the file meta information's (0002,0002) *Media Storage SOP Class UID* during read:

```py
from pydicom import dcmread
from pydicom import config

def fix_sop_class(elem, **kwargs):
    if elem.tag == 0x00020002:
        # DigitalXRayImageStorageForProcessing
        elem = elem._replace(value=b"1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.1.1.1")

    return elem

config.data_element_callback = fix_sop_class

ds = dcmread('path/to/file')
```

By changing the SOP Class UID, that processing is skipped and the dataset returned.